# How can I setup a simple web service using ASP.Net MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a client-based winforms application that parses a file and creates a **Game** object.

The plan is to have that client send the **Game** object to a webservice that is expecting that object type. Then on the server side, I would use Entity-Framework 4 to persist that information.

Essentially, that **Game** object is just a POCO/Model class.

How would I set things up on the server side so my application exposes a service and furthermore expects that type of object.

Thank you.

*snip*
Scratch that, it wasn't what I needed.

Comment: I fail to see how this problem has to do with asp.net mvc. Maybe you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of MVC's ModelBinder functionality to automatically compose your input models from form or query data, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Save(Game game)
{
    int id = game.Id;
    // Do work
    ...
```

And then on your client:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Game/Save");
string data = string.Format("Id={0}&Name={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(game.Id), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(game.Name));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.contentType= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
  writer.Write(data);
}

// Post the data.
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This is all overkill, there are technologies that already exist such as WCF services, etc which will handle the proxy generation and communication for you. Have you considered them?

Comment: I agree that WCF services would offer a very flexible solution. If the OP is still wanting to use MVC, then they could use a JsonValueProviderFactory - http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx which is registered by default in MVC3